# How to get the list of allowed values of an 'enum' field/check constraint?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, check-constraints

Suppose we have a 'person' table created with the following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  name VARCHAR2(50) ,
  gender VARCHAR2(50) CHECK( gender IN ('male','female','other') )
);
```

Is there a way to retrieve the list of authorized values of the 'gender' column? ie. [male, female, other] ?

Comment: Not easily.  You can look at `dba_constraints` and get the `search_condition` for the constraint.  Assuming that's less than 32k, you could get a `varchar2` variable with the text "name in ('male', 'female', 'other')".  You could then parse that variable to extract the three values that the `check` constraint allows.  If you're ever going to do that, however, it would make far more sense to create a `gender` table and a foreign key constraint rather than a check constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Check is a constraint and it can be obtained from the table `all_constraints` where the column `search_condition` will contain the enumeration ('male','female','other'), this column is of type LONG. The check constraint type is `C`.

To parse the LONG value, you can create a function:

```
CREATE or REPLACE function Find_Value
   (av_cname varchar2)
   RETURN varchar2
IS
   long_var LONG;
BEGIN
   SELECT SEARCH_CONDITION INTO long_var
   FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
   WHERE constraint_name = av_cname;

   return long_var;
END;
```

The following query will then get you what u need :

```
select Find_Value(constraint_name) from all_constraints
where table_name = 'your_table_name' AND constraint_type = 'C'
```

Comment: That will get the search condition; but you still need to parse the individual values out of the LONG value. And potentially have to handle `or` as well as `in`, and possibly transformations, so that isn't simple.

Comment: Am having trouble setting code block through mobile, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
with col_constraints as
   (select table_name,constraint_name,
                 extractvalue
               ( dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype
                 ( 'select search_condition from user_constraints where constraint_name = ''' || u.constraint_name || '''' )
               , '//text()' ) search_cond
   from user_constraints u
   where constraint_type = 'C'
   and table_name = 'PERSON'
   )
, sval as   
    (select substr(search_cond
                        ,instr(search_cond,'(',instr(upper(search_cond),' IN ')+4)+1  -- after opening parenthesis
                        ,instr(search_cond,')',instr(upper(search_cond),' IN ')+5)  -- pos of closing parenthesis
                        -instr(search_cond,'(',instr(upper(search_cond),' IN ')+4)-1) -- subtract start to get list length
             inlist_string           
    from col_constraints
    )
SELECT  regexp_substr(inlist_string,'[^,]+',1,level),level
from sval
connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT (inlist_string,'[^,]+');
```

As you can see, it is done in three parts:

1: use xmlgen to transfer the LONG to something workable (thanks to William Robertson)
2: extract just the list for the "IN"
3: use a recursive regexp_substr to split out the values into rows